# Jquery click function works on desktop, but not on mobile

Tags: jquery, css

Ok so I have a bundle of images on my page total of 8, when the user clicks on one of the images its applies a css circle above it to show its been selected, I achieve this by doing the following jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#panel1 .row img").click(function () {
            $("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("BlackcherryCircle");
            $("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("CoconutCirle");
            $("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("MangoCircle");
            $("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("StrawberryCircle");
            $("#hdnPanel1").val('');

            var name = $(this).attr("data-name");

            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

            switch (name) {
                case "blackcherry":
                    $(this).addClass('BlackcherryCircle');
                    break;

                case "coconut":
                    $(this).addClass('CoconutCirle');
                    break;

                case "mango":
                    $(this).addClass('MangoCircle');
                    break;

                case "strawberries":
                    $(this).addClass('StrawberryCircle');
                    break;

                default:
            }

            $("#hdnPanel1").val(id);

            getCombination();

        });
});
```

This works perfect fine on the desktop and tablets, but fails to trigger on the mobiles? am I missing some crucial?

Comment: You can reduce your removeClass calls with this: `$("#panel1 .row img").removeClass("BlackcherryCircle CoconutCirle MangoCircle StrawberryCircle");`

Comment: Second hint, you can use the `.data` method to get data-attributes with jQuery: `var name = $(this).data('name');
            var id = $(this).data('id');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use mousedown event for mobile instead of click. Run a check to detect if the device is mobile then

```
$("#panel1 .row img").mousedown(function () { // Your code goes here });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **touchstart** event.

```
$("#panel1 .row img").on('click touchstart', function () {
  //Your code
});
```